# Change default hover on woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and by default when I hover over a product thumbnail the hover presents the price and catergory.

Does anyone know how I would make this display custom text - (view product) NOT the price and category.

Unfortunately I am not proficient enough in php to elaborate anymore than that (I am assuming this is a php edit) but it is the default woocommerce settings so I am hoping someone has run into this problem in the past.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this has nothing to do with WooCommerce and has everything to do with your theme. There's simply not enough information here.

Comment: when searching the theme's forum for similar posts - it states it has everything to do with woocommerce and nothing to do with the theme. I have edited other areas of woocommerce in php that has been well documented. I just cant find any specific documentation on changing that specific element.

Comment: In default WooCommerce there is no hover effect in the shop loop or in the individual product page. Here's [Twenty Sixteen](https://wordpress-helgatheviking.c9.io/shop/) as an example. Without a link I can't confirm it, but unless I'm misunderstanding *where* the hover is occurring, I'm still convinced it is your theme.

Comment: http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title/  seems to suggest that you can remove the existing hover action with a `remove_action` call in your functions.php and replace it with something else of your own design. This is where the functions live http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/2.4.9/files/includes-wc-template-hooks/

Comment: This might also be of some use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357381/woocommerce-where-can-i-edit-html-generated-by-hooks - ahh - just realised it was by @helgatheviking so could be the right thing!  If it is a plugin you would need to find it and edit that though.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.

Helgatheviking, I followed your link to the twenty sixteen theme and your right, it would appear to be the theme, which is odd as they do seem to consistently redirect people to woocommerce help. I will read your articles - if I can get my head around loops an hooks, I could attempt to edit the themes woocommerce files.

Steve, removing the old one seems like a good place to start so I'll give that a go. Is there any way to use developer tools to single out which function is operating on an element so I know which piece of php I am dealing with and where to find it?